# Cant get variables from other php file

Tags: php

Here is my code in index.php

```
include_once "connect.php";

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$userName = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pwd1'];
$userName = stripslashes($userName);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (isset($_POST['Murad'])) {
  if ($firstname =="" || $lastname =="" || $username =="" || $password =="" || $email ==""){
    include "all.php";
    echo "";
    exit();
  }
 if (strlen($userName) < 3 || strlen($userName) > 16) {
       echo '<strong id="KIARTLAFF">3 - 16 characters please</strong>';
       exit();
} header("Location: main.php?/$firstname/$lastname/");}
?>
```

connect.php

```
<?
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '123');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
if(isset($_POST['Murad'])){
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link,'websiteusers' );
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$userName = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pwd1'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sqlb = "INSERT INTO websiteusers (fullname,lastname,userName,pass,email)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$userName', '$password', '$email')";  
if(mysqli_query($link,$sqlb)){

}else {
    echo mysqli_error($link);
}
 mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

And main.php

```
<?php 
include_once "connect.php";
?>
<title ><?php echo $firstname." ".$lastname;?></title>
```

I want to get variables from index.php to main.php.
I could not find any ways that could help me in interenet there were many includes i tried them but they did not work

Comment: Post them, Post them with form and use `$_SESSION`

Comment: you included connect.php instead of index.php in your main.php file

Comment: Do you want to redirect to main.php?

Comment: what is the purpose of `include_once "connect.php";` in main.php?

Comment: @CodeGodie i thought i can get variables from there

Comment: well you have to decide what you need. Are you going to redirect? or stay on the same page? if redirecting, then you would need to pass those in the url and retrieve them using GET. If staying on the same page, you would need to restructure your code so that you require/include main.php but it seems like that is not what you want

Answer (score 2):

A couple of problems here:

1. In your `if` conditional you have `if (..$username == ""..)` however `$username` is not declared, instead you have `$userName`, thus the `header()` never reached
2. You are using this: `header("Location: main.php?/$firstname/$lastname/");` This will redirect to that url correctly, but that wont do anything as you are probably thinking of `$_GET` , however that url is not a proper get url. you would need something like `main.php?firstname=$firstname?lastname=$lastname`. Which in return in main.php you would need to retrieve those Get parameters like `$fname = $_GET['firstname']`

---

**UPDATE:**

If you really want to do away with the whole redirect idea then you need to change your code a bit.

Assumming that this is the flow:

1. User submits a form from `someother.php`
2. form sends POST request to `main.php`

Then you would need to do the following:

1. remove the line where `header()` that resides in `index.php`
2. `main.php` should be something like this:

   ```
   <?php
   include "index.php";
   ?>
   <html>
       <head>
           <title><?php echo $firstname; ?></title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <div><?php echo $firstname; ?></div>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: so i can get first name and username from url right?

Comment: yes you can as long as its in the correct format in the URL

Comment: this url is right?                                                       http://localhost/murad/centil/o/main.php?firstname=a?lastname=aaaaaaaaa

Comment: @qwaaz Let me know if you need any more help. I can help you remotely if so

Comment: but how can i redirect user in index.php??

Comment: i dont have yahoo ig or snapchat ?

Comment: No i have teacher actually i ask him all questions but i wont see him one week this is the only question i need for now)

Comment: No problem. You are able to do both. You need to decide. See my answer. it tells you how to redirect or just include if needed. If you want to redirect you can pass data using GET or SESSIONs google that info for more details.